# Nautilus (Gnome Files) won't open any files when used as default file manager on Xubuntu

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, nautilus, xfce, filemanager

I used to be able to use Nautilus fine on Xubuntu 18.04 but since I recently did a reinstall Nautilus now refuses to open files when I double click them, there's just a small flicker and then nothing happens.

This only happens if I set Nautilus to the default file manager if I leave Thunar as the default and just open Nautilus directly everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1778069

In the post #11 we will see this:

> I had to remove the following entries from
>   ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list,
>   in the "[Added Associations]" section:
>
> x-scheme-handler/http=exo-web-browser.desktop
>   x-scheme-handler/https=exo-web-browser.desktop
>   x-scheme-handler/file=exo-file-manager.desktop
>   x-scheme-handler/trash=exo-file-manager.desktop
>   x-scheme-handler/mailto=exo-mail-reader.desktop;

It solved the problem for me.

Update:

As per #8 at the link these paths need to be checked as well: /usr/share/xubuntu/applications/defaults.list and ~/.config/mimeapps.list

Comment: This didn't work for me but it got me on the right track. I needed to check the other paths listed here as well.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1778069/comments/8

If you amend your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Nevermind I edited it for you.